# Shell script to open files in one folder, copy a specific line then open a file with the same name in another folder and edit the same line

Tags: bash, sed

Hi I'm trying to write a shell script to open files in one folder, copy a specific line then open a file with the same name in another folder and edit the same line

And here is my current code, what am I not doing right?

```
#!/bin/bash

source_folder=$1
target_folder=$2

for file in $(find $source_folder -name '*.po'); do
  file=$(open -r $file)
  start_line=$(grep -i "X-WagtailLocalize-TranslationID:" $file)
  line=$(echo $file | sed 's/.//' | grep -i "X-WagtailLocalize-TranslationID:" | sed 's/.//')
  close_file()
  file=$(open -w $file)
  sed -i '' -e 's/X-WagtailLocalize-TranslationID:.//g' $file
  close_file()
done
```

Comment: A simple input and desired output would help others to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very weird line of code:

```
for file in $(find $source_folder -name '*.po'); do
  file=$(open -r $file)
```

Why do you overwrite your loop variable? You'd better write something like:

```
for file in $(find $source_folder -name '*.po'); do
  file2=$(open -r $file)
```

(and obviously, beware of using `$file` and `$file2`)

Comment: It's probably odd indeed since I'm lost haha - when I try to add a file2 I get the following error: ./switch_po.sh: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `file=$(open -w $file)'
./switch_po.sh: line 25: `  file=$(open -w $file)' I'm unsure where to go from here - should I add file2 to that latter line also?

Comment: Yes, indeed. That too.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

In case of interest in the future this is what worked:

```
    #!/bin/bash

# Get the source and target directory names.
source_directory="source"
target_directory="target"

# Check if the source directory exists.
if [ ! -d "$source_directory" ]; then
    echo "Source directory not found."
    exit 1
fi

# Check if the target directory exists.
if [ ! -d "$target_directory" ]; then
    echo "Target directory not found."
    exit 1
fi

# Get the list of files in the source directory.
source_files=$(ls "$source_directory")

# Loop through the list of source files.
for source_file in $source_files; do

    # Check if the source file exists.
    if [ ! -f "$source_directory/$source_file" ]; then
        echo "Source file not found: $source_directory/$source_file"
        continue
    fi

    # Get the target file name.
    target_file="$target_directory/$source_file"

    # Check if the target file exists.
    if [ ! -f "$target_file" ]; then
        echo "Target file not found: $target_file"
        continue
    fi

    # Open the source file and read its contents.
    source_file_contents=$(cat "$source_directory/$source_file")

    # Find the line in the source file that starts with "X-WagtailLocalize-TranslationID:".
    source_line=$(grep "X-WagtailLocalize-TranslationID:" "$source_directory/$source_file")

    # Open the target file and read its contents.
    target_file_contents=$(cat "$target_directory/$source_file")

    # Find the line in the target file that starts with "X-WagtailLocalize-TranslationID:".
    target_line=$(grep "X-WagtailLocalize-TranslationID:" "$target_directory/$source_file")

    # If both lines were found, replace the target line with the source line.
    if [ -n "$source_line" ] && [ -n "$target_line" ]; then
        source_line=${source_line##*: }
        target_line=${target_line##*: }
        target_file_contents=${target_file_contents//$target_line/$source_line}
    fi

    # Write the new contents of the target file to disk.
    echo "$target_file_contents" > "$target_file"

done

echo "Done."
```

Comment: Never use `ls` to get a list of filenames. Instead you should use `find`, or a loop such as `for source_file in "$source_directory"/*`. Also, your way of reading a file in a var, edit that var, and rewrite the file is weird and dangerous and will fail for huge files. You should consider editing directly the file in place (for example with `sed -i`).